# Access Unity StreamingAssets on Android

Tags: android, directory, assets, unity-game-engine

I wrote some code to get all the folders inside a folder inside the StreamingAssets and then to get all the files in that folder.
It works well on Windows but I can't get it to work on Android.

Here is the code :

```
foreach (string s in Directory.GetDirectories(model.path + "/Levels")) {
        GameObject el = (GameObject)Instantiate(listButton, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        el.transform.SetParent(grid1.transform);
        string[] words = s.Split('/');
        #if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_EDITOR_WIN
                            words = s.Split('\\');
        #endif
        el.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = words[words.Length - 1];
        el.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => {
            MapSizeButtonClick(Int32.Parse(el.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text));
        });
    }
```

I had to add the #if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN for windows because of the '\'.

Then for the files inside that folder I wrote this :

```
foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(model.path + "/Levels/" + model.mapSize + "/" + model.colorNumber)) {
        string[] words = s.Split('/');
        #if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_EDITOR_WIN
                    words = s.Split('\\');
        #endif
        words = words[words.Length - 1].Split('.');
        if (words[1] == "json") {
            GameObject el = (GameObject)Instantiate(listButton, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
            el.transform.SetParent(grid3.transform);
            el.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = words[0];
            el.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => {
                levelButtonClick(Int32.Parse(el.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text));
            });
        }
    }
```

I'm using UnityEngine.UI.Directory but I read that it can't be use on Android and I must use WWW instead. Something like this :

```
string xmlSetUpPath = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/xml/xmlSetUp.xml";

        WWW book1WWW = new WWW(book1Path);
        yield return book1WWW;
        if(!File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/xml/book1.xml"))
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/xml/book1.xml", book1WWW.bytes); 
        }
```

However I couldn't find anything like Directory.getFiles() or Directory.getFolder(). So I thought I could use WWW to check if the file exists (as the file names are 1.json, 2.json, 3.json) and iterate until a file doesn't exist.

But I would also need to check if a folder exists for the 1st part of the script and I can't find how to check if a folder exists with WWW. (My folders names are also 1,2,3,4...)

So how to check if a folder exists with WWW ?

Or what else can I do ?

**UPDATE :**

I updated the code, now it looks like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(model.path, "Levels/" + i.ToString()))){
            GameObject el = (GameObject)Instantiate(listButton, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
            el.transform.SetParent(grid1.transform);
            el.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = i.ToString();
            el.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => {
                MapSizeButtonClick(Int32.Parse(el.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text));
            });
        }
    }
```

I use path.combine() and check every folder from 0 to 100. It works on Windows but it still doesn't work in Android.

The path is set like this :

```
#if UNITY_IPHONE
        path = Application.dataPath + "/Raw";
    #endif

    #if UNITY_ANDROID
        path = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets";
    #endif

    #if UNITY_STANDALONE || UNITY_EDITOR
        path = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets";
    #endif
```

**QUESTION UPDATE**

I made a script that generate the file paths. The paths are always the same : "FolderNumerotedFromYToX/FolderNumerotedFromYToX/FileNumerotedFrom1ToX.json". The generation works but the writing to JSON doesn't. It outputs "{}".

```
        // Generate level list
    List<KeyValuePair<int, List<KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>>>> l;
    l = new List<KeyValuePair<int, List<KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>>>>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "StreamingAssets"), "Levels/" + i.ToString()))) {
            l.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, List<KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>>>(i, new List<KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>>()));
            for (int j = 1; j < 100; j++) {
                if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "StreamingAssets"), "Levels/" + i + "/" + j))) {
                    l[l.Count - 1].Value.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>(j, new List<int>()));
                    int k = 1;
                    while (true) {
                        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "StreamingAssets"), "Levels/" + i + "/" + j + "/" + k + ".json"))) {
                            l[l.Count - 1].Value[l[l.Count - 1].Value.Count - 1].Value.Add(k);
                        }
                        else
                            break;
                        k++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    string ljson = JsonUtility.ToJson(l);
    var lsr = File.CreateText("Assets/StreamingAssets/levels.json");
    lsr.WriteLine(ljson);
    lsr.Close();
```

Can you help me finding a way to store this to a file ?

Comment: IMO you should use Path.Combine() to concatenate a valid path to a string. And just where did you read that you can't use "normal" File operations? File.Exists() should just work fine.

Comment: I will try Path.Combine(), thanks ! I read it here http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/reading-xml-and-texture-files-in-streamingassets-folder.247035/ and in other places, they say you must use WWW on Android. Maybe I got a little bit confused, File.Exists() should work but it's about Directory.GetFiles() and Directory.GetFolders().

Comment: basically you **must and can only use** `Application.persistentDataPath` in all cases - all platforms - everywhere - no matter what.

Comment: Why should I use persistentDataPath ? I used Application.dataPath like it's said in the Unity documentation. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html

Comment: I made an update with the new code in the post.

Comment: if anyone trusted the Unity documentation, civilization would collapse.

Comment: If I write path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/StreamingAssets" it doesn't work on Windows. PersistantDataPath contains the root folder of the project and I want the Assets folder.

Comment: I just realised that dataPath is the path to the project and PersistantDataPath is the path to the build (in appData on Windows). But this folder is empty when I build in the editor so I guess I should use #if UNITY_EDITOR for when I build in the editor.

Comment: I used this code for the path to StreamingAssets : path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/assets/StreamingAssets";. It doesn't work and persistentDataPath contains "/data/data/com.Project.Puzzle/files/". My phone isn't rooted and I can't go into this folder.

Comment: I'm getting tired searching... (more than 4 hours now) I found another code where they use Application.streamingAssets. https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/14142/Get-Unity-StreamingAssets-file-path-with . Should I use this ?

Answer (score 6):

It may sound hard, but you really have to use the `WWW` class to access your files from `StreamingAssets` on Android.

And you have to keep a list of your filenames, to be able to access them, as there seems to be no way to use something like `File.Exists` or `Directory.GetFiles`.

Example:

```
WWW www = new WWW(source);
yield return www;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
{
    // make sure the destination directory exists
    File.WriteAllBytes(destination, www.bytes); 
}
else
{
    // error handling
}
```

Your source files (base) path should look like this:
`jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/`

---

### From the docs:

> Note that on Android, the files are contained within a compressed .jar
>   file (which is essentially the same format as standard zip-compressed
>   files). This means that if you do not use Unity’s WWW class to
>   retrieve the file then you will need to use additional software to see
>   inside the .jar archive and obtain the file.

Source: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html

Comment: I made a script which generate the list of the files (Added to the post). But now I don't know how to store it in a file. The JSON part doesn't work and juste writes "{}" to the file. Can you help me ?

Comment: Are you able to load/read the files on Android now? That was the actual question, wasn't it? But ok.. do you create the JSON stuff during runtime? If so, you should not put them in Streaming Assets.. Use Application.persistentDataPath for such data.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem I created pre-compilation script which will run before the compilation; this script will list the names of the files you want to access later in text file

```
 #if UNITY_EDITOR
 using UnityEditor.Build;
 using UnityEditor;
 using System.IO;

 public class BM_AndroidBuildPrepartion : IPreprocessBuild
 {
     public int callbackOrder { get { return 0; } }
     public void OnPreprocessBuild(BuildTarget target, string path)
     {
         // Do the preprocessing here
         string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles("Assets/Resources/Prefabs/alphabet", "*.prefab");
         System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("Assets/StreamingAssets/");
         using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Assets/StreamingAssets/alphabet.txt", false))
         {

         foreach (string filename in fileEntries) {
                 sw.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename));
         }

         }
     }
 }
 #endif
```

then I read the text file and you can access the files in same way but you have to put them inside your project in Assets/StreamingAssets/

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        string  path = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/alphabet.txt";
          WWW wwwfile = new WWW(path);
          while (!wwwfile.isDone) { }
          var filepath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Application.persistentDataPath, "alphabet.t");
          File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, wwwfile.bytes);

          StreamReader wr = new StreamReader(filepath);
              string line;
              while ((line = wr.ReadLine()) != null)
              {
              //your code
              }
   #endif
```